# How to create a txt file with a String content and download that txt file

Tags: java, filewriter, fileoutputstream

I am using java and struts. I have a scenario where there is **'Download'** link in the page. After clicking on this link the control goes to the **Action class**, where I have String content which I need to write to a **.txt** file and then download that txt file.

Eventually whenever we click on the download link, we should be able to download a txt file having content a particular string.

I used below piece of code,

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileNameWithDirectory);
outputStream.write(fileContentString.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
ActionForward forward = new ActionForward("doc/" + filename);
forward.setName(filename);
forward.setRedirect(true);
return forward;
```

Also I tried with `FileWriter` in place of `FileOutputStream` like,

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileNameWithDirectory);
fileWriter.write(fileContentString);
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

But always instead of downloading the txt file, the control opens a new window where the String content is written.
Please suggest me, how would I able to download that **.txt** file.

Comment: What are you using on your server? Servlets?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Content-Disposition: attachment` to say browser, that it should download the file, not to open it.

See more details [here](https://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-download-file-from-website-example/)

Also Struts has [DownloadAction](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/struts-1.3.10/org/apache/struts/actions/DownloadAction.html), you may use it as well.

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment` is working and I got download option, but after downloading the .txt file, No content is written there, it's downloading Blank.

Comment: @Prosenjit could you update your question with changed code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the file and then redirect to it. You can set a http response header called [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and then print your data into the http response body.

use it like this

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");
```

of course this depends on which technology stack you're using.

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment` is working and I got download option, but after downloading the .txt file, No content is written there, it's downloading Blank.

Comment: What code are you using to write the content to the http response body?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your text file to stream. and set content type as you wanted to download.
**response.setContentType("application/pdf");**

```
try {
      // get your file as InputStream
      InputStream is = ...;

      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, convertedTextFiletoStream);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '{}'", fileName, ex);
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
```